# MelissaData Replacement?

Tags: vb.net, street-address

We currently use MelissaData to scrub our addresses. We have been pretty unhappy with the product and the support in general (considering how expensive they are). Can anyone recommend a good replacement? We want a product that we can download the database and don't want to use any web service type of calls to do the address scrubbing.

Comment: Not to second-guess you, but in the interest of my curiosity: what concerns do you have about a web service call? Is there a reason you prefer to maintain such a massive database locally? (Maybe it's just a 'corporate' thing out of your control?)

Comment: Our primary development is on an app used by internally. Every time someone retrieves anyone (the basis of our business) it checks their address. If our internet was down (has happened before) or the service was down it would halt everything to a screeching halt which we can't afford.

Answer (score 3):

In order to have a complete address database, you will need to get it from the source, which in the United States is the US Postal Service.  Once you have their data, you will need to parse it into a format that is usable.  This is not a simple task since the USPS stores the data in their own proprietary format and the documentation is often "less than helpful".  It literally can take years to refine your algorithms to handle all of the wacko edge cases that street addresses have.  However, that would allow you to keep the data local instead of calling a webservice.  You will need to license from the USPS their ZIP+4 data, and then be prepared to integrate new date each month as it is released.  If you are going to scrub your addresses for mailing with the intention of obtaining mailing discounts, you will also need to go through the process of becoming CASS-Certified by the USPS.  (This is not a task for the faint of heart, and not a quick process--As I mentioned earlier, it can take years to perfect.)

If your core operations are address verification, it is probably worth it go down that road since the time you spend developing your custom application will support your business.  However, if you are not in the address verification business and would prefer to do other things rather than jumping through USPS certification and maintenance hoops, I recommend finding an address verification provider whose workflow will integrate nicely with your requirements.  This will allow you to focus on what you do best instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

In the interest of full disclosure, I am the founder of [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com). We provide street address verification.

Answer (score 1):

A good replacement is CODE1 from the postal division of the USPS.

CODE1 will have to be installed on the SQL server - something that has to be considered when using this.

Also, to update the db it needs to run a DTSx package nightly, weekly or quarterly depending on how often you wish to update the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying ZP4 from www.SemaphoreCorp.com. The product and web site have an older look to them, but they've been doing this for years, and it's only $99 for a disc. No, I don't work for them or get any compensation, but I work for GreatData.com (we sell primarily 5-digit ZIP Code products) and have recommended them to lots of clients over the years and haven't heard any complaints.